# Is it possible to unpad a file that is not padded

Tags: aes, padding

I used `"AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"` to encrypt some files. But I did not provide any identifier to detect if the file is encrypted or not. Now one way to detect if a file is encrypted or not, that I can think of, is to try to decrypt it and see if there is a padding miss match.

Now my question is, 
***Is it possible for some random file to match the padding scheme?***

Comment: Be very careful with decrypting and looking for a padding mismatch. This can lead to [padding oracle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack).

Comment: @mikeazo: want to turn that into an answer?  I can't think of anything to add...

Comment: If you had used an [tag:authenticated-encryption] scheme, then checking if the file can be correctly decrypted *would* be a reliable (if rather inefficient) way to distinguish encrypted and unencrypted files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is quite possible that after decryption, a file that was not encrypted falsely appears to be encrypted with correct padding.

For a file of random byte length, there is probability 1/16 (6.25%) that its length is that of a valid encrypted file, and then there is probability just below 1/255 (≈0.392%) that after decryption, the last block ends with `01`, or `0202`, or `030303`, or `04040404`...

All in all, nearly one random file (of both random length and content) out of 4080 would wrongly pass the test.